# Transformation order in rendering a SVG marker

Tags: svg, marker

I want to know in what order should I apply transformations to render a marker that has a

1. Has a transformation element - transform="scale"
2. MarkerUnits attribute - set to "strokeWidth"
3. and a "refX" attribute set

The SVG looks like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="3.51615in"
    height="0.244444in" viewBox="0 0 253.163 17.6" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st3">
```

```
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
    .st1 {marker-end:url(#mrkr4-6);stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.239976}
    .st2 {fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.068959096269629}
    .st3 {fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;font-size:12;overflow:visible;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3}
]]>
</style>
<defs id="Markers">
    <g id="lend4">
        <path d="M 2 1 L -0 0 L 2 -1 L 2 1 " style="stroke:none"/>
    </g>
    <marker id="mrkr4-6" class="st2" refX="-29.002700270027" orient="auto"
            markerUnits="strokeWidth">
        <use xlink:href="#lend4"/> <!--transform="scale(-14.501350135013)"--> 
    </marker>
</defs>
<g id="shape1-1" transform="translate(7.78146,-0.16)">
    <path d="M0 8.96 L230.64 8.96" class="st1"/>
  </g>
```

I am first scaling a matrix by the stroke width of "shape1-1" (0.239976), then translating that matrix by the refX (-29.002700270027), I then translate the matrix to where the marker should go on the path (last point (230.64 8.96), this is an end-marker). And eventually I account for the transform attribute on the use element. This does not seem to be the proper order. It isn't rendering properly.

As an aside, a related question. when in my marker element I set MarkerUnits to "strokeWidth", which stroke should it use the stroke-width set on the path element (0.239976) or the one on the Marker element (0.068959096269629)?

Comment: Does the SVG1.1 spec chapter on markers not answer this? http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#Markers

Comment: On my first question I did not see anything in the specs all I saw is that " *Markers are drawn such that their reference point (i.e., attributes ‘refX’ and ‘refY’) is positioned at the given vertex. In other words, a translation transformation is constructed by the user agent to achieve the effect of having point (‘refX’ and ‘refY’) within the marker content's coordinate system (after any transformations due to the ‘viewBox’ and ‘preserveAspectRatio’ attributes) align exactly with the given vertex* ". It does not say anything regarding and explicit transform attribute

Comment: As for my second question about which element's stroke width is applied. There seems to be a bit ambiguity in the specs. In describing the attribute _If markerUnits="strokeWidth", the contents of the ‘marker’ represent values in a coordinate system which has a single unit equal the size in user units of the current stroke width in place for the **graphic object referencing** the marker_

Comment: Later in details on how markers are rendered it is described as  _A temporary new coordinate system is established by the attribute ‘markerUnits’. If it equals 'strokeWidth', then the  coordinate system is the result of scaling  by **the current value of property ‘stroke-width’** ._ Is this the Markers own stroke-width attribute if provided or is its own always ignored?